# Subject and complement

Tags: subject-complement

Is it correct to have a singular complement (if the complement is a noun) when the subject is plural?

For example:
*These are a cheap source of entertainment.*

Similarly, is it correct to have a plural complement (if the complement is a noun) when the subject is singular?

For example:
*The biggest problem is the stray dogs.*

Comment: Yes, it's possible in both cases.

Comment: @Userabc Thanks. Can you please give details of the relevant rules?

Comment: Your examples are fine. There is often no agreement of number with "be". Compare this ex with specifying "be":  "All we need now is some new curtains". But not where there is semantic incompatibilty between the terms: we can't say *"the person who complained was my parents". Mismatches with plural subj and sing comp are also possible with ascriptive "be", e.g. "Our neighbours are a nuisance"